# Insert a Record into Amazon's DynamoDB using Curl (via low level API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, libcurl

I'm trying to insert an item into DynamoDB table using Curl. I know there is the AWS SDK and AWS-CLI but [as per this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html) it seems that it is also possible to insert an item via simple HTTP API or `Curl` only.

Anyway, I've been trying it for a while but I keep getting this error in response:

`{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}`

**Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

Here is my script:

```
$date = date('r');
$priv_key = getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY');
$access_key = getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID');
$length = strlen($value);
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $date, $priv_key, TRUE));

$cmd = "\
    curl -d @test.json \
        -H \"Host: dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;\" \
        -H \"Accept-Encoding: identity\" \
        -H \"Content-Length: $length\" \
        -H \"User-Agent: Curl\" \
        -H \"Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0\" \
        -H \"Authorization: $access_key:$signature\" \
        -H \"X-Amz-Date: $date\" \
        -H \"X-Amz-Target: DynamoDB_20120810.PutItem\" \
        https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\"\
";

print ($cmd);
print system($cmd);
```

And here are the contents of `test.json` (the file being sent by Curl)

```
{
    "TableName": "cache",
    "Key": {
        "id": {"S": "1"},
        "data": {"S": "test"}
    }
}
```

Again I know I can very easily do it via SDK but I just want to know why this isn't working? I'm doing everything as per the docs to understand the inner workings of the SDK. Any Ideas?

Comment: I too would like to manipulate DynamoDB directly via HTTP. It is helpful when trying to debug issues with other clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can see that is wrong is the Content-Type should be "application\json". Here is a working example for a GetItem:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: identity' \
  -H 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/20190505/ap-southeast-2/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept-encoding;cache-control;content-length;content-type;host;postman-token;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 253' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'User-Agent: postman' \
  -H 'X-Amz-Date: 20190505T235951Z' \
  -H 'X-Amz-Target: DynamoDB_20120810.GetItem' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
   "TableName": "test-table",
   "Key": {
       "Eventdate": {
           "S": "2019-03-28"
       },
       "Eventid": {
           "S": "00001"
       }
   },
   "ConsistentRead": true,
   "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL"
}'
```